# Compiling Boost C++ libraries on VS2012 project

Tags: c++, math, opencv, visual-studio-2012, boost

I am trying to build a project which has Boost and OpenCV dependencies. Other projects having similar dependencies seem to work fine but this throws the following errors:

```
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp(42): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp(42): error C2734: 'boost::math::T' : const object must be initialized if not extern
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp(42): error C2365: 'T' : redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp(42): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '>='
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp(44): error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp(44): error C2923: 'boost::math::tools::promote_args' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T1'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp(44): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp(44): error C2059: syntax error : '<cv-qualifer>'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp(44): error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp(44): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(20): warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'round'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(20): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(20): error C2433: 'T' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(20): error C2734: 'boost::math::T' : const object must be initialized if not extern
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(20): error C2365: 'T' : redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(20): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '>='
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(29): error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(29): error C2923: 'boost::math::tools::promote_args' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T1'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(29): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(29): error C2059: syntax error : '<cv-qualifer>'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(29): error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(29): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(30): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

What is the probable issue here?

I have changed the name of the macro round to something else and now its past these errors. But now, another error has sprung up: Actually this was a linux implementation. I am trying to run it in Windows and thereby I added the timeoftheday implementation in windows to the code.

```
1>eval_ffd.obj : error LNK2005: main already defined in demo.obj
1>eval_ffd.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl eval_forest(struct FaceForestOptions,class std::vector<struct FaceAnnotation,class std::allocator<struct FaceAnnotation> > &)" (?eval_forest@@YAXUFaceForestOptions@@AEAV?$vector@UFaceAnnotation@@V?$allocator@UFaceAnnotation@@@std@@@std@@@Z) already defined in demo.obj
1>eval_ffd.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl gettimeofday(struct timeval *,struct timezone *)" (?gettimeofday@@YAHPEAUtimeval@@PEAUtimezone@@@Z) already defined in demo.obj
1>face_forest.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl gettimeofday(struct timeval *,struct timezone *)" (?gettimeofday@@YAHPEAUtimeval@@PEAUtimezone@@@Z) already defined in demo.obj
1>face_utils.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl gettimeofday(struct timeval *,struct timezone *)" (?gettimeofday@@YAHPEAUtimeval@@PEAUtimezone@@@Z) already defined in demo.obj
1>head_pose_sample.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl gettimeofday(struct timeval *,struct timezone *)" (?gettimeofday@@YAHPEAUtimeval@@PEAUtimezone@@@Z) already defined in demo.obj
1>image_sample.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl gettimeofday(struct timeval *,struct timezone *)" (?gettimeofday@@YAHPEAUtimeval@@PEAUtimezone@@@Z) already defined in demo.obj
1>multi_part_sample.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl gettimeofday(struct timeval *,struct timezone *)" (?gettimeofday@@YAHPEAUtimeval@@PEAUtimezone@@@Z) already defined in demo.obj
1>train_ffd.obj : error LNK2005: main already defined in demo.obj
1>train_ffd.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl gettimeofday(struct timeval *,struct timezone *)" (?gettimeofday@@YAHPEAUtimeval@@PEAUtimezone@@@Z) already defined in demo.obj
1>train_headpose.obj : error LNK2005: main already defined in demo.obj
1>train_headpose.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl gettimeofday(struct timeval *,struct timezone *)" (?gettimeofday@@YAHPEAUtimeval@@PEAUtimezone@@@Z) already defined in demo.obj
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc110-mt-1_54.lib'
```

Comment: Make sure that you have boost included and in _Additional Include Directories_ you have the path to boost, also not sure if you need some defines

Comment: Yes boost is included in the path and the Addn. Incl. Dir. Other projects are running with this configuration. Only this project is giving this error.

Comment: So where is main defined?  Are you implementing it in a header file that is included by demo.cpp, eval_ffd.cpp, train_ffd.cpp, train_headpose.cpp?  Same goes for some of the other functions you have there.  Just put the protoctype for the functions in the headers if you need to and the implementation in the cpp files

Comment: Actually this project has multiple mains. It has 2 features and according to the feature we want to test, we have to include the respective cpp files in the makefile. I got it wrong initially. It later worked out. Thanks a lot Pete for your responses :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something is declaring a macro called 'round'.

In your errors, see the line:

```
1>C:\boost_1_54_0\boost_1_54_0\boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp(20): warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'round'
```

Do a file wide search for `#define round` in any library dependencies and in your own code.

Depending upon what defines it, you may have a few options for fixing the problem:

- Don't include the header
- See if the header does not define `round` if there is some predefined macro that you can include in your build settings.
- `#undef` round before including boost
- `#include` the header in your precompiled header and `#undef` round